# Help solving first order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve the following initial value problem:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = - \frac{3x^2+y}{x+2y}$$

$$y(0) = 1$$

I have to find the solution as an explicit form of $x$. I have no idea how to go about it. I tried some separating and substitutions, but to no avail....

Answer (score 1):

The ODE is exact. This means the solution is of the form $F(x,y)=C$ and the ODE hence is of the form $dF(x,y)= F_x(x,y)dx+F_y(x,y)dy=0$ so one can just integrate $F_x(x,y)$ and $F_y(x,y)$ to recover the solution.

To see this, expand and reorganize the ODE to

$$
(3x^2+y)dx+(x+2y)dy=Mdx+Ndy=0
$$

Exactness is seen by checking that $M_y=N_x$, which is just verifying that $F_{xy}=F_{yx}$. If this doesn't hold, then the ODE is not of the form 
$dF(x,y)= F_x(x,y)dx+F_y(x,y)dy=0$. In our case, $M_y=N_x=1$ so the ODE is exact.

The solution is found by integrating $M=F_x$ with respect to $x$ and integrating $N=F_y$ with respect to $y$:

$F(x,y)=\int F_x \partial x =\int M\partial x = x^3+xy+f(y)$ for some function $f(y)$

$F(x,y)= \int F_y\partial y = \int N\partial y = xy+y^2+g(x)$ for some function $g(x)$

Choose $f(y)=y^2$ and $g(x)=x^3$ then we have $F(x,y)=x^3+xy+y^2=C$ is the solution.

Substitute the initial condition $(x=0,y(0)=1)$ into $F$ and we get $1=C$. Thus, the solution is given by $x^3+xy+y^2=1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = - \frac{3x^2+y}{x+2y}$$
$${(x+2y)}{dy} = - {(3x^2+y)}{dx}$$
$$dxy+2y{dy} = - {3x^2}{dx}$$
Integrate
$$xy+y^2+x^3=C$$
Apply initial condition.
$$y(0)=1 \implies C=1$$
$$\boxed {xy+y^2+x^3=1}$$